# How to obtain id of the entity on the map?

Tags: openstreetmap

Let's say I am looking the map where there is a lake or the forest. How to find out find an id of it? If the lake/forest is divided into smaller chunk, how I can select given chunk and get id of it?

*Selecting chunks (or entire objects) is possible in OSM editor, I can see plenty of description there, but I don't see id of it (just for the record, I don't intend editing data, I used editor just to try to read the id).*

Comment: @AnatolySukhanov, Brilliant, it has even the needed query in the examples. Many thanks. Could you please post your comment as an answer (I cannot mark comment as solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify objects direcly on the OpenStreetMap website: https://www.openstreetmap.org - zoom in to the region of you interest and activate the object identify tool - the last one of the symbols on the right side with the question mark. It only works if you zoom in (zoom level 14 to 19). Click on the map where the object of your interest is. In the example, I'm interested in the restaurant:

[image]

Now, all object that are inside the orange circle are listed on the left side in the upper part - in the lower parte, you find listed all the surrounding objects (like the park, the town, administrative unit, country that contains the clicked coordiante). You can now select the object you are interested in, in my case: the Regal Pizza - you might also select other objects like Park = Cathedral Garden:

[image]

The next window shows you all the details of the selected object - the tags and values like name = Regal Pizza:

[image]

You can now use this e.g. in QGIS: install the QuickOSM plugin, zoom the the area where you object is located in and than run the query with the value form above. This will load the object as a vector layer to QGIS:

[image]

The solution proposed by Anatoly Sukhanov is also very useful: when you have identified the tag/value pairs you're interested in, you can make an easy query with the https://overpass-turbo.eu/ website, using the wizard. Zoom e.g. to the extent of the the whole city or even country and introduce for example `amenity=restaurant` or `leisure=park` to get all restaurants or parks in the respective bounding box of your map canvas

[image]

After the query run successfully, you see all the objects tagged with `leisure=park` - on the left side, you see the query, you could change it manually here. If you are happy, you can export the results in different formats like goejson, GPX or KML.

[image]

For background information about OpenStreetMap id see:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Permanent_ID

See also this tutorial: https://mapsaregreat.com/geographic-data-mining-and-visualisation-for-beginners/overpass-turbo-tutorial.html

Comment: This is even better, thank you very much for so detailed answer! With visual feedback (it draws contours around selected items) inspecting elements is really easy.