# How to add Google Maps query to QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps

I was wondering if there is an easy way to transfer multiple locations searched on Google Maps to QGIS. My issue is that I can't find a shapefile for the data I'm looking for (location of beaches) but this data is easily available on Google Maps. Is there a way to transfer the Google Maps search results to QGIS?

I'm quite new to QGIS and I'm using 3.18.2-Zürich.

Comment: Would OpenStreetMap data also fit your needs? See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379236/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368774/88814

Comment: Do you have an area of interest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At risk of 'ignoring' your question about Google Maps, the QuickOSM plugin for QGIS might be suitable for your needs. It provides an easy way to find and download OpenStreetMap data. You can use the query `natural = beach`.

The answers linked in the comment from @Babel explain how to identify features in OSM to find the `Key-Value` combination.

[image]

Result:

[image]