# Extract house number layer from OSM

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, extract

I am using QGIS 3.22. Is there a way to extract the house number data from the OSM into shapefile or something else?

Answer (score 3):

To extract all OSM features that have a house number, you can use [Overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) or QgickOSM plugin in QGIS.

Use this query in Overpass Turbo:

```
addr:housenumber=*
```

See here for how to identify the tag used for housenumbers:
[How to obtain id of the entity on the map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379211/how-to-obtain-id-of-the-entity-on-the-map/379236#379236)

*Using QuickOSM plugin, looking for all features containing a tag `addr:housenumber` in the extent of the map canas. The result is loaded as polygon layer, containing the orange houses (the others have no hounse-no. in the OSM database). See the values in the attribute table (yellow):*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try to download the shapefile databases fractionated by administrative divisions worldwide by using this website:

https://download.geofabrik.de/

the way of how we can download data from this website are explained here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/beginner-guide-to-download-the-openstreetmap-gis-data-24bbbba22a38

After all, unzip your file and find the following shapefile

```
gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1
```

you will have all the buildings provided to OSM. Bear in mind, that OSM is self-contributed by various users worldwide, so sometimes some buildings might be missing in your area.