# Getting bus routes departing from bus stop from OpenStreetMap data to QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, route

I design a map, where I want to depict the number of public transport lines that are in walking distance from each building block of a city.

How do I give each stop its routes and its total amount of routes?

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://www.openstreetmap.org, zoom in to one of the bus stops and click on it with the object identify tool. Then you get an overview how this object is tagged. Select the tag that identifies the bus stop / the information you are interested in. For more details how to do that, see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379236/88814) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368774/88814).

For Zurich's bus routes, I used the key:value tag `network=ZVV`, ZVV being the operator of Zurich's public transportation. I use [QuickOSM plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) in QGIS that downloads points, lines and polygons. Once you have downloaded the data, have a look to the attribute table to see which attribute has the information you're interested in.

In my case, in the line layer's attribute `name`, the routes are listed as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

To get the information from the line layer (routes) to the point layer (stations), you can use [Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) or use [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with QGIS expressions and [overlay-functions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest).